# Java Instance Variable referred within local variable. Memory, thread safety and finalization

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-threads, java-memory-model

I have class MyClass which has a method with variable - an instance of OtherClass as shown below

```
public class Myclass{ 
   public void meth1(){
　
　　OtherClass other = new OtherClass();  
    other.perform();
　　　　　
    }

}

public class OtherClass{

private Map<String, String> ops = new HashMap<>();

public void perform(){

  // put/ remove values in ops 
    }

}
```

This is a multi-threaded environment
When a thread executes the method meth1() where does Map is created? in heap? Is there thread safety issues wrt to the map declared as instance variable. 
When local variable is garbage collected, I assume map is also garbage collected. Please correct if I am wrong.

Note: I know there are data corruption when we have instance variables within multi-threaded environment
However this is slightly difference scenario

Comment: If it's about multiple threads calling `meth1` only nothing can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a thread executes the method meth1() where does Map is created?
>   in heap?

Yes. Everything you create with `new Whatever()` is stored on the heap, both the `OtherClass` instance as well as its `HashMap` (as its initialization includes the `new HashMap<>()` expression). And everytime you execute `new Whatever()`, you get a completely fresh instance on the heap.

> Is there thread safety issues wrt to the map declared as instance
>   variable.

No, not in your example. Only if multiple threads were accessing the same instance of `OtherClass`, thread safety might become an issue. In your case, every thread of execution creates its individual `OtherClass` instance (in the local variable `other`), uses only that one, and does not hand it out to any place where another thread might see it.

> When local variable is garbage collected, I assume map is
>   also garbage collected.

Yes, as long as you don't add code that hands the Map out to some other part of the software.

Instances are garbage collected when they are no longer referenced by any "live" variable/parameter/object/... In your case, the `ops` HashMap is only referenced (stored) by the `ops` field of its enclosing `OtherClass` instance. So, when this instance is no longer reachable, the Map becomes unreachable as well, and thus ready for garbage collection.

One remark: the garbage collection won't happen the very same moment when something becomes unreachable, it's scheduled by some elaborate optimized algorithm. The only thing you can be sure of is that it'll happen before you run out of memory.

> Note: I know there are data corruption when we have instance variables
>   within multi-threaded environment However this is slightly difference
>   scenario

That's true only the opposite direction: You can't run into thread safety / data corruption issues if you don't have instance or class fields.

True is: If you use instance or class fields in a multi-thread setting, you have to be careful. But e.g. read-only instance fields (ones that you only set in the constructor and never change later) are generally safe.

Answer (score 1):

The `OtherClass` object will be created on the heap, and the reference to that will be created on the stack. Due to `stack confinement`, this code is totally thread safe. Thread safety issues arise only when the state of an object is shared across multiple threads. Since this object can be accessed by only the thread that calls the method, it is not shared. As soon as the stack of popped off, the object will be garbage collected.

Comment: … *can* be garbage collected. There is no guaranty about whether or when this will happen, but it’s irrelevant anyway.

Comment: Yes actually I had removed it from my answer to be precise. But there is no guarantee, you are right.